# Checking if a number is a multiple of 9 and its degree-9 in c

Tags: c, function, recursion, definition

"A well-known trick to find out if an integer *N* is a multiple of nine is to compute the sum *S* of its digits. If *S* is a multiple of nine, so is *N*. Besides that, if the number of digits in S is x, we say that the degree-9 is x".

The entry is a file such that each line contains a positive integer. A line containing the number 0 indicates the end of the
input. The numbers provided in the entry are up to 1000 digits

My code for this problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long int numberDigits(long long int value)
{
   long long int i=0;
   if(value!=0){
        i++;
        return i+numberDigits(value/10);
    }
   else

        return 0;

}

int main(){

    char n[1001];
    n[0] = 1;
    long long int digits[1001], sumDigits = 0, i = 0;

    while (n[0] != '0')
    {

        scanf("%s", n);
        if(n[0] == '0')
            break;
        while(n[i])
        {
            digits[i] = (int)n[i] - 48;
            sumDigits += digits[i];
            i++;
        }
        if(sumDigits % 9 == 0)
            printf("%s is a multiple of 9 and has 9-degree %lld.\n", n, numberDigits(sumDigits));
        else
            printf("%s is not a multiple of 9.\n", n);
        sumDigits = 0;
        i = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting "Wrong Answer" from the electronic judge. Any tips on how to improve the solution?

Comment: Must you use recursion?

Comment: you are reading in a string with `scanf` rather than a number...what if the test throws in something that isn't a number to throw you off?

Comment: You said that the entry is a file, what happens if one of the entries is `0123`?

Comment: n is an array of characters.  Why are you setting n[0] to 1?

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: 1) Are you searching string end with `while (n[0] != '0')`? In that case be aware that the string terminator is `\0` or `0`, not `'0'`, which value is 0x30. 2) Do you really need an array of 1001 long long digits? Assign directly the conversion from `n` to a temporary integer variable, instead.

Comment: Looking better you are using leading 0 in string as the exit condition. But what happens if you insert string numbers as n? Does it work as expected?

Comment: Maybe you need to skip leading zeros.

Comment: It would be better to implement `numberDigits` using iteration instead of recursion in case the electronic judge does not optimize out the tail recursion, possibly leading to a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
    i= 0; sumDigits= 0;
    while (n[i]) sumDigits += n[i++] - '0';
```

and then after the loop, `i` has the number of digits.

Comment: It's a bit unorthodox, but `i` and `sumDigits` are reset but at the end of the main loop, not at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

In general the function  `numberDigits` is wrong because for a number equal to 0 the function returns 0 digits.

The array `digits` is redundant.

In general an entered string can start from '0'. So the condition of the while loop is incorrect.

It is unclear from the assignment whether 0 is considered as a valid number divisible by 9.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the algorithm can be implemented. I excluded 0 from valid numbers. If a string consisting from all characters '0' is allowed then substitute this if statement

```
if ( sum != 0 && sum % Divisor == 0 )
```

for this one

```
if ( sum % Divisor == 0 )
```

Here is the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int numberDigits( unsigned long long int n )
{
    const unsigned int Base    = 10;

    return 1 +  ( ( n /= Base ) == 0 ? 0 : numberDigits( n ) );
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 1000 };
    char s[N + 1];

    while ( scanf( "%s", s ) == 1 && !( s[0] == '0' && s[1] == '\0' ) )
    {
        const unsigned int Divisor = 9;

        unsigned int sum = 0;

        for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
        {
            sum += s[i] - '0'; 
        }


        if ( sum != 0 && sum % Divisor == 0 )
        {
            printf( "%s is a multiple of %u and has %u-degree %u.\n", 
                    s, Divisor, Divisor, numberDigits( sum ) );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s is not a multiple of %u.\n", s, Divisor );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the following way

```
9 is a multiple of 9 and has 9-degree 1.
18 is a multiple of 9 and has 9-degree 1.
123456789 is a multiple of 9 and has 9-degree 2.
99999999999999999999 is a multiple of 9 and has 9-degree 3.
```